# Which strands in Splice are potential Angelics?

Tags: achievements, splice

In Splice, some strands are considered "Potential Angelics", and can be solved in fewer than the alloted moves.

Not all strands can be Angelic, however, and as far as I can see, the only way to tell if a strand is angelic or not is after completing it, where the post-level menu has a "Potential Angelic" moniker if the strand can be angelic.

As I'd rather not have to recomplete all the levels to see which strands I've yet to achieve angelic status on, I was hoping there was some way of identifying these strands from the main menu.

Comment: Before even completing a strand, you can tell if it's a potential angelic by looking for the marker in the lower left corner of the screen. It appears on every level that can be solved in less than the allowed moves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to tell what strands are Potential Angelic from solely the level select menu, but I did find [a list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/673589-splice/answers?qid=328575) of Potential Angelic levels:

---

- Sequence 1: 102, 105, 106
- Sequence 2: 204, 205
- Sequence 3: 302, 303, 304
- Sequence 4: 403, 405, 407
- Sequence 5: 501, 504, 505, 506, 507
- Sequence 6: 601, 603, 604, 607
- Sequence 7: 701, 702, 704, 706, 707

---

- Epilogue 1: e102, e103, e104, e105, e106, e107
- Epilogue 2: e201, e202, e205, e207
- Epilogue 3: e301, e303, e304
- Epilogue 4: e401, e403, e404, e405

Comment: Good enough for me!

Answer (score 2):

The "potential angelic" moniker should also replace the bar code for the particular level when you are highlighting it, but I am not sure if this happens from the start or if this only happens once you've finished the level at least once before.

Another possible indicator of whether or not a level has an angelic solution is that four-tone sequence that is played at the beginning of some levels. Again, I am not sure if this only plays after you have played a level or if it actually does work as a notification, but I have gone back into the game and have noticed that the sequence is only played if the level has an angelic solution. There is also a slight flash of the angelic solution symbol in the lower-left corner of the screen that accompanies this sequence, but, again, I am not sure if this does happen from the start of if it only happens after you have attempted the level.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only appears once you've beaten it.

Comment: It's as I expected, then. I'm sorry that I couldn't have been of more help.